# Java-script object - get variable name

Tags: javascript, dynamic, variables

To begin with, I'm not even sure, if it is the right way to do it.

Let's say, i have script (jquery included) like this:

```
foo = function() {

    this.bar = function() {
    alert('I\'m bar');
    }

    this.test = function() {
    $('body').append('<a onclick="my_var.bar();">Click me</a>');
    }

this.test();

}

var my_var = new foo();
```

Is there any way, i could make variable "my_var" dynamic inside function "foo".
So I could do something like

```
$('body').append('<a onclick="'+the_variable_which_im_assigned_to+'.bar();">Click me</a>');
```

Thank you

//Edit:

I'm sorry if i wasn't clear enough, because I'm not quite sure of what I'm trying to do myself.

My goal is to replace line

```
$('body').append('<a onclick="my_var.bar();">Click me</a>');
```

with

```
$('body').append('<a onclick="'+what_ever_should_go_here+'.bar();">Click me</a>');
```

So when i call

```
var my_var = new foo();
var your_var = new foo();
var our_var = new foo();
```

I would be able to call functions inside each object (after they append something into document body).

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to switching from the inline event handler, you'll need to use a [closure](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) to access the Foo instance within the handler.

```
function Foo() {
    var self = this;
    this.test = function() {
        $('body').append(
            $('<button>something</button>').click(function () {
                self.bar(); return false;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was doing it completely wrowng way.

Comment: SLaks' code phrasing (chaining all the calls) is cleaner than mine. Keep the use of `self` and the click handler, but use his `click(...).appendTo(...)`. Note also that a button might make more sense than a link while still calling out to the user to click it (without having to say "click me"), depending on the element's exact purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should use anonymous handler functions instead of inline events, like this:

```
$('<a href="#">Click Me</a>')
    .click(function() { my_var.bar(); return false; })
    .appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the general plan you want/need to use to attach event handler, yeah, send in the **name** of the variable to the function that `foo` refers to:

```
foo = function(name_of_the_variable_which_im_assigned_to) { [...] };
```